# How do I monetize a blog with 30K pageviews per month from South Asia without using adsense,affiliates and without selling info products?

Tags: marketing

Basically the title.  I'm wondering what monetizing streams are there? I'm looking for sponsored ads. But I'm not sure what kind of ads could I get in south asia. It is a blog about computer science engineering. I don't want to  use adsense  because it's  paying me 0.5$ for 1000 pageviwews. I don't want to use affiliates because obviously, students in south asia don't buy anything from affiliate links. Plus tech students use adblockers. I am making literally no money with this website. I am thinking of spamming the site with random guest posts as they pay handsomely but I also realize it's not a long term solution.

How do I monetize this blog? I am not interested in making courses or ebooks because I don't think I'm that much qualified.

Answer (score 1):

Sell subscriptions to your users or create premium content.

Comment: Eloquently put.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to look at other websites, similar to yours, that have ads other than adsense and see whether you can apply to get those on your own site.

As an example, a clean and simple ad system used by C++ Reference:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

See at the top-left corner.

---

I have to agree that:

1. adsense is really not paying much at all (although that is in part because small players are of not much interest and thus the $0.01 ads abound on those small websites...)
2. for the last few years, adsense literally litters your website and as a result reduces your readership which then makes your website even smaller and thus not likely to get higher rates.

Comment: Carbon ads pay 1$ for 1000 views from what I've  read. So, it's not much.